# How to draw Transparent Polygon in OpenGL-ES 2.0?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to draw a semi transparent(say , alpha = 0.5) polygon in openGL-es 2.0 . How to do that?. Few things i tried.
1.I made gl_Fragcolor.w= 0.5 in fragment shader.
2.Disabled Depth related things.

I don know how to enable blending in openGL-es 2.0. I read it somewhere it is implemented automatically. is it so?. Any small help is appreciated.

Comment: I have given a transparent color instead of changing the alpha. It works fine.GlBlend is not scrapped off in Es-2.0. When you have Transparent OPenGL Layer we see the drawing either appear(alpha > 0) or disappears(alpha=0) with blending. When the view is opaque we can see the blending perfectly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to enable alpha blending. For a faq on how to do that: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Transparency_Sorting .

To enable the effect you want:

```
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Note that enabling alpha blending will hurt performance somewhat - so only do it on the triangles that must have alpha blending enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me know what do you think about the comment i have added in that question?.

Comment: The link leads to an empty page :/

Comment: But still, useful answer +1 if you could update the link target would be great